# no title in the task bar after wake up from pm-suspend on Ubuntu 16.04 running LXDE

Tags: lxde

I guess a picture is worth 1000 words (see the bottom of the screen)

[image: No titles any more]

All the titles go away on wake up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the system? Are you running Unity or GNOME? 
Try their Tweak Tools. They solve most problems with launchers. 
If that doesn't work, try apt-get update.
Or else Reinstall(last resort!)